# How to parent vertices for clothing animation

Tags: animation, rigging, cloth-simulation, parent

I'm following a cloth simulation tutorial about mating a portion of a dress to a portion of a rigged model, to allow the lower part of the dress to flow with the simulation, but the upper part of the dress to conform to the rigged mesh of the woman.  It sounds incredibly simple, but for the life of me, I can't get the dress verts to bind properly to the rig (or the rigged mesh).

[This is tutorial, pegged to the specific location where I am stumped.](https://youtu.be/_TfkAjQ-ytI?si=Eo4E6YRpPlGnXCp3&t=42).  The author says "parent the vertices to the rig".  I've tried multiple approaches, but cannot get the verts to bind properly.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello, select the dress, shift select the armature and parent With Automatic Weights? If it doesn't work please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: pls provide blend file because you gave us no technical information at all what you have done so we can check it out on our own. thx.

Comment: and please...do click on the checkmark left of answers if they are helpful. I just checked your historie and you never did do that. By this you help improving this site and you reward the people who answer you for free on this site. Thanks. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cdeh.png